# Ebooks or PDFs on AD .NET

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have a background in AD infrastructure and powershell.
However, I don't have much background on C# and .NET 
I'm thinking of putting aside some time to learn the how to write useful applications using C#/visual studio using .NET on Active Directory.
Is there is a good book (preferably PDF/ebook) which I can read? Preferably if the books covers how to get some common tasks in AD groups:

1. List item
2. detecting circular nested groupings
3. writing reports on groups
4. creating forms to create applications for help desk level support people
5. Where and what classes are available in .net and pros and cons of each
6. some basics of how to use hash tables, lists, dynamic arrays, working with xml
7. get various reports on user based on password expiry, account expiry etc.

Comment: You can search for books here: https://it-ebooks.info/tag/programming/

Comment: take a look at this codeproject article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C